# Convergence of Improper Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)q(x)e^{-x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

*Problem*: Let $P_3$ be the set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $3$, show that

$$<p(x),q(x)> =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)q(x)e^{-x^2}dx$$

It is an internal product in $P_3$.

I have solved this problem, but I am very curious that the term $ e ^ {- x ^ 2} $ appears in the integrand, I know that its role in the definition is to allow the improper integral to converge, because if you omit this, and we define

$$<p(x),q(x)> =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)q(x)dx$$

taking $ p (x) = x = q (x) $, clearly the integral does not exist. My question is, how can I prove that $$ <p (x), q (x)> = \int _ {-\infty} ^ {\infty} p (x) q (x) e^{- x ^ 2 } dx $$ converges for every pair $ (p (x), q (x))\in P_3 $?

Comment: By taking products $pq$, we get potentially up to a sixth degree polynomial. Prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x^2}dx$ exists for each $n = 1, \cdots, 6$. Hint: Each integrand has a maximum somewhere, bound the integral by that max times $e^{-x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral into the sum of the 2 integrals
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 p(x)q(x)e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{\infty} p(x)q(x)e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x $$
$p(x)q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $6$ or less, so for sufficiently large values of $x$, you have $|p(x)q(x)|<e^{2x-1}$, and by the comparison test, it remains to show that the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{2x-1}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x-1)^2}\mathrm{d}x $$
is convergent, which is true since this is just the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). For the convergence of the first integral (from $-\infty$ to $0$), take $e^{-2x-1}$ instead.